# AnimatedSwitcher with IndexedStack

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I have to use IndexedStack to maintain the state of my widgets for my BottomNavigationBar.
Now i want to use AnimatedSwitcher (or an alternative) to create an animation when i switch tabs.
I'm having issues getting AnimatedSwitcher to trigger on change of IndexedStack. I'm having IndexedStack as the child of AnimatedSwitcher, which obviously causes AnimatedSwitcher to not trigger because the IndexedStack widget doesn't change, only it's child.

```
body: AnimatedSwitcher(  
  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),  
  child: IndexedStack(  
    children: _tabs.map((t) => t.widget).toList(),  
    index: _currentIndex,  
  ),  
)
```

Is there any way around this issue? By manually triggering the AnimatedSwitcher, or by using a different method to create an animation?
I also tried changing the key, but that obviously resulted in it creating a new IndexedStack everytime the a new state was created, and therefor the states of the tabs was lost as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you need to use IndexedStack.

You can add custom animation and trigger it on changing tabs, like that:
[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  final List<Widget> myTabs = [
    Tab(text: 'one'),
    Tab(text: 'two'),
    Tab(text: 'three'),
  ];

  AnimationController _animationController;
  TabController _tabController;
  int _tabIndex = 0;
  Animation animation;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _tabController = TabController(length: 3, vsync: this);
    _animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      value: 1.0,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
    );
    _tabController.addListener(_handleTabSelection);
    animation = Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(_animationController);
    super.initState();
  }

  _handleTabSelection() {
    if (!_tabController.indexIsChanging) {
      setState(() {
        _tabIndex = _tabController.index;
      });
      _animationController.reset();
      _animationController.forward();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> _tabs = [
      MyAnimation(
        animation: animation,
        child: Text('first tab'),
      ),
      MyAnimation(
        animation: animation,
        child: Column(
          children: List.generate(20, (index) => Text('line: $index')).toList(),
        ),
      ),
      MyAnimation(
        animation: animation,
        child: Text('third tab'),
      ),
    ];

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      bottomNavigationBar: TabBar(
        controller: _tabController,
        labelColor: Colors.redAccent,
        isScrollable: true,
        tabs: myTabs,
      ),
      body: IndexedStack(
        children: _tabs,
        index: _tabIndex,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyAnimation extends AnimatedWidget {
  MyAnimation({key, animation, this.child})
      : super(
          key: key,
          listenable: animation,
        );

  final Widget child;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Animation<double> animation = listenable;
    return Opacity(
      opacity: animation.value,
      child: child,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah i know that's the reason why it's not switching. But i need to preserve the  state of the tabs, and the only way i've found to do that was using an IndexedStack. Do you know any alternatives to IndexedStack that are maintain the state of the tabs and that is compatible  with AnimatedSwitcher?

Comment: You can save tab state at upper level and pass it down from there. What kind of data you need to store?

Comment: Most tabs contain for example a listview, for which i want to preserve the scroll position. If i were to save the tab state at upper level, how would i do that if my tabPage is the main route using namedRoutes?

Comment: Persistent state and state management in itself are the big themes. It is possible that using indexedState could works well in your case.

Comment: @Kherel thanks so much, you save my time, can we have `reveal effect` instead?

Answer (score 43):

This is a cleaner way to use `IndexedStack` with animations , I created a `FadeIndexedStack` widget.

https://gist.github.com/diegoveloper/1cd23e79a31d0c18a67424f0cbdfd7ad

**Usage**

```dart
body: FadeIndexedStack(  
    //this is optional
    //duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
    children: _tabs.map((t) => t.widget).toList(),  
    index: _currentIndex,  
  ),
```

Comment: You save my day! Thank you!

Comment: You are my Hero. Very good work! Flutter should implement that in their Framework! Appreciate it, thank you very much.

Comment: You are awesome

Answer (score 3):

Here's example how to do it:

```dart
PageTransitionSwitcher(
   duration: Duration(milliseconds: 250),
      transitionBuilder: (widget, anim1, anim2) {
    return FadeScaleTransition(
      animation: anim1,
      child: widget,
    );
  },
  child: IndexedStack(
    index: _currentIndex,
    key: ValueKey<int>(_currentIndex),
    children: [
      Page1(),
      Page2(),
      Page3()
    ],
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to add key to your IndexedStack and a transitionBuilder method to your AnimatedSwitcher widget like so...

```
AnimatedSwitcher(
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1200),
            transitionBuilder: (child, animation) => SizeTransition(
              sizeFactor: animation,
              child: IndexedStack(
                key: ValueKey<int>(navigationIndex.state),
                index: navigationIndex.state,
                children: _tabs.map((t) => t.widget).toList(),  
              ),
            ),
            child: IndexedStack(
              key: ValueKey<int>(navigationIndex.state), //using StateProvider<int>
              index: navigationIndex.state,
              children: _tabs.map((t) => t.widget).toList(),  
            ),
          ),
```

There are also cool other transitions like ScaleTransition, SizeTransition, FadeTransition

Answer (score 0):

Try to add key to your IndexedStack so your code will look like:

```
body: AnimatedSwitcher(  
  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),  
  child: IndexedStack(
    key: ValueKey<int>(_currentIndex),
    children: _tabs.map((t) => t.widget).toList(),  
    index: _currentIndex,  
  ),  
)
```

The key is changed so AnimatedSwitcher will know that it's child is need to rebuild.

Comment: This doens't work as intended because it does not keep state between switched widgets in IndexedStack

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you could solved this:

1. First create a new widget using the code bellow.
2. This widget uses `PageView` which will give you a nice sliding animation by default but you could customise the animation if you want.
3. To keep the state of the children, Just use AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin inside each child's widget.

   ```
   class IndexedStackSlider extends StatefulWidget {
     /// Constract
     const IndexedStackSlider({
       super.key,
       required this.currentIndex,
       required this.children,
     });

     /// The current index
     final int currentIndex;

     /// The list of children
     final List<Widget> children;

     @override
     State<IndexedStackSlider> createState() => _IndexedStackSliderState();
   }

   class _IndexedStackSliderState extends State<IndexedStackSlider> {
     late PageController _pageController;

     @override
     void initState() {
       super.initState();
       _pageController = PageController(initialPage: widget.currentIndex);
     }

     @override
     void dispose() {
       _pageController.dispose();
       super.dispose();
     }

     @override
     void didUpdateWidget(IndexedStackSlider oldWidget) {
       super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
       if (oldWidget.currentIndex != widget.currentIndex) {
         _pageController.animateToPage(
           widget.currentIndex,
           duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
           curve: Curves.easeInOut,
         );
       }
     }

     @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return PageView.builder(
         controller: _pageController,
         physics:
             const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), // Disable swipe between pages
         itemCount: widget.children.length,
         itemBuilder: (context, index) {
           return AnimatedBuilder(
             animation: _pageController,
             builder: (context, child) {
               return Align(
                 alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                 child: child,
               );
             },
             child: widget.children[index],
           );
         },
       );
     }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I was a bit disappointed myself that this wasn't supported out of the box with IndexedStack so I took a stab at making an enhanced version that would support custom transitions (with a bit more control) AND still maintain state of the children.

I made a repo with a tiny test app here:
https://github.com/IMGNRY/animated_indexed_stack

Any feedback or PR's are welcome!