# Fade and Bounce animation in Flutter

Tags: flutter, animation, flutter-animation

How to make Animation in flutter in below reference YouTube Link.

I've used fade animation of @diegoveloper -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/59535289/14949568

But I want to make  animation like this -> https://youtube.com/shorts/qcnn34e_wrY

for your reference I've uploaded Video on YouTube.